# Prevent goggles from fogging

Tags: equipment, squash

I play squash and sweat a lot. I wear protective goggles. The fogging is very inconvenient, and impairs significantly my vision by the 3rd game usually.

Is there any tip/recommendation to minimize fogging?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  it deals with equipment not specific to any sport, i.e. protective goggles. It is a boat programming question.

Comment: @Nij reread the question: it's about squash goggles. For most sports, any gogges are fine. For squash, the specificity is that they need to be very protective (it's dangerous because of the close proximity), and anti-fog (squash is very intense and causes players to sweat a lot. So yes, it is sport specific.

Comment: To minimise fogging is not sport-specific. The only answer already lists things that would be told by swimmers and runners and other sports.

Comment: This is not an answer , but a suggestion: try [Rain-X](https://www.rainx.com/product/glass-water-repellents-cleaners/rainx-original-glass-treatment/#.V8d19vb6sdU) It works great on cars!

Answer (score 3):

I play in safety glasses without suffering unduly from fogging, although I often sweat heavily. If it occasionally happens, I clean them with a dry handkerchief. I think it's a feature of quality squash glasses that they are designed to allow air flow. Perhaps changing the model you use might help.

I also wear a "bandana" twisted up and tied around my forehead. This serves to prevent sweat from dripping onto the glasses during play. If you can successfully prevent this, fogging seems to be less of a problem.

Answer (score 2):

Some seem to use [their own saliva, baby shampoo, shaving cream, etc.](http://swimming.about.com/od/swimgoggles/qt/Swimming-Goggle-Anti-Fog.htm), but when I run a long distance, I always spray [anti-fog agents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-fog). But how effective it would be will largely depend on how much you sweat and how you move.

I don't think it would be more effective when playing squash than running because you have to bend over more often to hit the ball dropping more sweat to your glasses.

Anyway, anti-fog agents work, but don't expect too much.